# How do I web scrape this link and iterate through the page numbers?

Tags: python, web-scraping, python-requests

My goal is to web scrape this url link and iterate through the pages. I keep getting a strange error. My code and error follows:

```
import requests
import json
import pandas as pd

url = 'https://www.acehardware.com/api/commerce/storefront/locationUsageTypes/SP/locations?page='

headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:98.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/98.0',
}


#create a url list to scrape data from all pages
url_list = []

for i in range(0, 4375):
  url_list.append(url + str(i))

response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
data = response.json()

d = json.dumps(data)
df = pd.json_normalize(d)
```

Error:

```
{'items': [{'applicationName': 'ReverseProxy', 'errorCode': 'UNAUTHORIZED', 'message': 'You are Unauthorized to perform the attempted operation. Application access token required', 'additionalErrorData': [{'name': 'OperationName', 'value': 'http://www.acehardware.com/api/commerce/storefront/locationUsageTypes/SP/locations?page=0&page=1'}]}], 'exceptionDetail': {'type': 'Mozu.Core.Exceptions.VaeUnAuthorizedException'}
```

This is strange to me because I should be able to access each page on this [url](https://www.acehardware.com/api/commerce/storefront/locationUsageTypes/SP/locations?page=0)

Specifically, since I can follow the link and copy and paste the json data. Is there a way to scrape this site without an api key?

Comment: Hi Because you are UNAUTHORIZED. ``You are Unauthorized to perform the attempted operation.  http://www.acehardware.com/api/commerce/storefront/locationUsageTypes/SP/locations?page=0 Application access token required``

Comment: Please refer this link might help https://stackoverflow.com/a/48427689/13888486

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works in your browser because you have the **cookie token** saved in you **local storage**.
Once you **delete all** cookies, it does not work when you try  to navigate to API link **directly**.
The token cookie is **sb-sf-at-prod-s**. Add this cookie to your **headers** and it will work.
I do not know if the **value** of this cookie is **linked to my ip address**. But if it is and it does not work for you. Just change the value of this cookie to one from your browser.
This cookies maybe is valid only for some request or for some time.
I recommend you to put some **sleep** between each request.
This website has **security antibot** [Akamai](https://www.akamai.com/es/products/bot-manager).

```py
import requests
import json

url = 'https://www.acehardware.com/api/commerce/storefront/locationUsageTypes/SP/locations?page='
headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:98.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/98.0',
    'cookie': 'sb-sf-at-prod=at=%2FVzynTSsuVJGJMAd8%2BjAO67EUtyn1fIEaqKmCi923rynHnztv6rQZH%2F5LMa7pmMBRiW00x2L%2B%2FLfmJhJKLpNMoK9OFJi069WHbzphl%2BZFM%2FpBV%2BdqmhCL%2FtylU11GQYQ8y7qavW4MWS4xJzWdmKV%2F01iJ0RkwynJLgcXmCzcde2oqgxa%2FAYWa0hN0xuYBMFlCoHJab1z3CU%2F01FJlsBDzXmJwb63zAJGVj4PIH5LvlcbnbOhbouQBKxCrMyrmpvxDf70U3nTl9qxF9qgOyTBZnvMBk1juoK8wL1K3rYp51nBC0O%2Bthd94wzQ9Vkolk%2B4y8qapFaaxRtfZiBqhAAtMg%3D%3D'
}
#create a url list to scrape data from all pages
url_list = []
for i in range(0, 4375):
    url_list.append(url + str(i))
response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
data = response.json()
d = json.dumps(data)
print(d)
```

I hope I have been able to help you.

Comment: that's incredible. How did you find the anti-bot?

Comment: So it does work with that above token, but how did you find that under the developer tab?

Comment: Install plugin for chrome Wappalyzer it will show you all technologies that has the website. 
Yes, click F12 on browser->Application -> Cookies. See oficial documentation https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/storage/cookies/